# Eclipse INI Configuration problem

Tags: eclipse, virtual-memory

I am working on a project which is really big and even if I increase the virtual memory, on refreshing the project, Eclipse crashes. The error is *java heap space error*.

This is the current setup:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.200.v20090519
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
```

If I increase it any more, Eclipse won't start.

Comment: See [What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few comments:

- You shouldn't define twice `launcher.XXMaxPermSize`
- You shouldn't use 512M (only 512m, see "[FAQ How do I increase the permgen size available to Eclipse?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_permgen_size_available_to_Eclipse?)")
- Depending on your JDK used for launching Eclipse, you might want to stick with Sun option `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

Even though those aren't the heap space parameters, they might influence how Eclipse runs.

Comment: It still crashes :( the project is ~2gb of code it crashes when refreshing

Comment: @kantu: are the settings of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse helping here? What version of Eclipse are you using? (v20090519 seems old) Any chance of trying with a 3.6.2 and the latest JDK possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best configuration for Eclipse NEON and o.s. Windows 10 with 4GB of Ram:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
–launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
–launcher.defaultAction
openFile
–launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
–launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
–launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/javaw.exe
–launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

If you have 8GB of Ram modify -XX:PermSize=512m and -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m.
For complete example see here : 
https://lentux-informatica.com/best-configuration-eclipse-ini/